# How do I migrate from one Synology NAS to two redundant Synology NAS on different locations?

Tags: remote, redundancy, synology-diskstation

I bought a Synology NAS for myself, a few years ago, and I would like to get another one that would be located at one of my relatives.

My current Synology has 2 disks that are redundant (default behavior IIRC).

What I would like is to have 2 Synology NAS (one on each location), with 2 disks each, but with the redundancy from one place to the other.

If possible, I would like to have bi-directional redundancy (for example, disk A1 gets copied to B2 and B1 to A2, but other ideas are welcome).

My question is double:

1. What do I need to buy? Do I need the very exact model I already own or can I buy another one? Can the disks have a different size as the ones I own or should I also look for the same disks?
2. How do I migrate? I mean… technically. How do I connect them via the Internet (I don't have a static IP address) and what do I do with the data already in my Synology?

Note that it's a private NAS only used by my family. It's not at all a problem if it's offline for a time, as long as the data are preserved.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/tutorial/How_to_sync_data_between_multiple_Synology_NAS_via_Cloud_Station)?

Comment: No, I haven't, but I did now! Thanks for the resource.